# Can't open Tor Browser in Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.4

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, error, mac

I have downloaded Tor three times and I keep getting the message:

**Tor Browser Profile Problem**

> You cannot run Tor Browser from a read-only file system.  Please copy
>   Tor Browser to your Desktop or Applications folder before trying to
>   use it.

After downloading the file, I have drug it to both my Applications folder and the Desktop and used both the click on icon to open process and by clicking Control-Open. I click yes on the button that warns that the application was downloaded from the Internet to open anyway, and then I get the "read-only" error.

I changed my preferences to download applications form anywhere, then downloaded again. Same problem.

I do not use, nor have I downloaded Firefox. I use Chrome or Safari, could that be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you extracted Tor?   I believe it downloads in a compressed folder

Comment: Make sure that if you download the DMG as the root user, you then run the executable as the root user. Same goes for a normal user. You can't run the executable as a normal user if you've downloaded and unpacked as the root user.

Answer (score 2):

What you downloaded is a DMG — a disk image.  When it opens, it is a read-only filesystem like a CD or DVD.  You have to copy the application **out of** the DMG before you can run it.

And then you have to run it on the same account that copied it out of the DMG, because it has to write to a file that is inside of the application.  So, each user that is going to run it has to have his or her own copy of the application.